# What is the syntax to import only a single method of a type?

Tags: rust

How could I pull out only `Duration` instead of `*`? Is it possible to pull out only `seconds`?

```
use chrono::*; 

// Returns a Utc DateTime one billion seconds after start.
pub fn after(start: DateTime<Utc>) -> DateTime<Utc> {
    start + Duration::seconds(1000000000)
}
```

Comment: It is preferred to post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question as well as others hunting for one of your questions.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to only import a method of a type. Note that `Duration::seconds` isn't a method — it's an [*associated function*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#associated-functions). You can't directly import these either.

If you *really* wanted something like this, I see two options:

1. New delegating function

   ```
   fn seconds(x: i64) -> chrono::Duration {
       chrono::Duration::seconds(x)
   }
   ```

   This is simple and obvious.
2. Static function pointer

   You *could* bind `Duration::seconds` to a static function pointer:

   ```
   static seconds: fn(i64) -> chrono::Duration = chrono::Duration::seconds;
   ```

   This will create warnings because statics should have uppercase names. I wouldn't do such a thing.

---

Please re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/)'s chapter titled [The Module System to Control Scope and Privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-modules-and-use-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html). You had to read over many sections before you got to the syntax for the [glob operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-modules-and-use-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html#bringing-all-public-definitions-into-scope-with-the-glob-operator). Those sections answer your first question:

```
use chrono::Duration;
```

You type the names of the [*items*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html) you wish to import. Importable items include:

- a module
- a function
- a type alias
- a struct
- an enumeration
- a union
- a constant
- a static
- a trait